Even after selecting Sandbox, Data Loader tries to login to production
I am using version 62.0.2. I select Sandbox and provide the proper user credentials. Login fails, with message:

Error: Check your username and password+Security Token, entered in the
form passwordXXXXXXXXXX where XXXXXXXXXX is your security token. If
you still can't log in, contact your Salesforce admin.

I try it with and without security token, no success. When I check the Data Loader log file (on my Windows machine it is located in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp), it says:

Failed to authenticate using the authentication service URL
https://login.salesforce.com specified for Production environment.
Error: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

And when I check the login history on the sandbox, I can see that no attempt is made to login, so I guess Data Loader is really trying to login in production. I cannot see anything there, since the user name is a sandbox user name.
Is this a bug in Data Loader or do I need to change something in the settings? This is a relatively new feature, in previous versions you had to specify the login domain in the settings and it was there that you specified login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com. Both of these values are now in the settings, but it looks like only the production settings are being used.

The obvious work-around is to replace login.salesforce.com in the settings by test.salesforce.com, then it works :-(

Have you found solution? I have seme issue

We are experiencing the same issue. Changing the Production address is not a go-forward solution. Was a ticket opened for this?

@JeffAlthaus It looks like the sources for DataLoader can be found at https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader, including instructions on how to report an issue. That looks like a lot of work. 62.0.2 is still the latest release. There are release notes, but they do not contain any information on what is new or changed in the release.

@SanderdeJong  when i tried with   it worked for me for sandbox. Might be while going to prod we need to chage the value to login.salesforce.com. Not sure the way I am doing is correct but since it worked for me I am following this

I got it working by saving a config.properties that I had generated from running the data loader into the folder with my process-conf.xml. Until that point, it had a default config.properties, which went to login.salesforce.com, and it didn't matter what I said in the process-conf.xml.
My config.properties are below.
loader.csvTab=false
process.operation=extract
process.useEuropeanDates=true
dataAccess.readUTF8=true
dataAccess.writeUTF8=true
sfdc.endpoint=https\://test.salesforce.com
process.statusOutputDirectory=C\:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Results

